# Angular: find memory leak on route change

Tags: javascript, angular

i want implement a feature for detect memory leak on routing changes.

With this snippet:

```
const getMemory = () => (window.performance as any).memory.usedJSHeapSize / (window.performance as any).memory.jsHeapSizeLimit;
```

The idea is, I retrieve the current usage of memory on `NavigationStart` and compare it with the memory usage on `NavigationEnd`, the difference is memory leak.

The goal is founds some things like unsubscribed subscription.

An example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">Login</a> |
    <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">Home</a> | 
    <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/catalog">Catalog</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {

  private memoryStart = 0;

  constructor(private router: Router){

        const getMemory = () => (window.performance as any).memory.usedJSHeapSize / (window.performance as any).memory.jsHeapSizeLimit;

        this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
          switch (true) {
            case event instanceof NavigationStart: {
              this.memoryStart = getMemory();
              break;
            }
            case event instanceof NavigationEnd: {
              console.log('Memory leak', (getMemory() - this.memoryStart));
              break;
            }
            case event instanceof NavigationCancel:
            case event instanceof NavigationError: {
              break;
            }
            default: {
              break;
            }
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Are my idea correct?

Comment: I could be wrong, but js has a built-in garbage collector, and it decides for itself when it should clean up. It could as well be that it just stores some memory a bit longer than you expect. I suppose your best bet would be to just use the performance tab of chrome devtools

Comment: Heap size changing all the time dynamically because there are many different objects allocated (not only subscriptions). In my option your calculations will be unreliable.